# Change Language Of All iOS Simulators

Tags: ios, swift, shell, automation, simulator

We have the issue that with every new Xcode version all of our simulators are re-created in with system language German and system region Germany. But we need to work with a special "development language". In our case that is `en_BZ`.

Additionally when I try to set the language now wirth Xcode 14 the simulator crashes and the only solution to bring it back is to erase its data.

How can I change system language/region permanently so I don't have to set that tediously with every new Xcode version and for every simulator device?

Answer (score 1):

This is actually possible suing the tool `simctl`. Using the following set of commands this can be fully automated:

```shell
xcrun simctl list -j "devices" | jq -r '.devices | map(.[])[].udid' | parallel 'xcrun simctl boot {}; xcrun simctl spawn {} defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLanguages -array en; xcrun simctl spawn {} defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLocale -string en_BZ; xcrun simctl shutdown {}'
```

### Explanation

The `{}` is a placeholder provided by `parallel` and it represents the respective `udid` obtained in the first steps above. This is what the single commands do, one by one:

- `xcrun simctl list -j "devices"`: Lists all devices that are also available in Xcode in JSON format.
- `jq -r '.devices | map(.[])[].udid'`: Filters the `udid` of each device from the JSON output. It uses the tool `jq` which is a super powerful JSON parser. You have to install that using `brew install jq`.
- `parallel [...]`: This launches the following set of command instructions *in parallel*. This is super useful since the first one, booting all simulators takes a lot of time. Doing this one by one would take forever. Please `brew install parallel` first.

  - `xcrun simctl boot {}`: Boots each simulator.
  - `xcrun simctl spawn {} defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLanguages -array en`: Sets English as one pf the preferred languages.
  - `xcrun simctl spawn {} defaults write "Apple Global Domain" AppleLocale -string en_BZ`: Sets English as used system language and Belize as system region.
  - `xcrun simctl shutdown {}`: Shutdown each simulator again.